# Getting empty data frame while merging two dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I am trying to merge two dataframes based on some columns but getting empty dataframe. Can you please help me to get proper solution?

Explain:

df1:

```
   kol_id thrc_nm   jnj_id
0  101152     VIR  7124166
```

df1.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 4 columns):
kol_id     1 non-null object
thrc_nm    1 non-null object
jnj_id     1 non-null object
           1 non-null object
```

df2:

```
  kol_id     jnj_id              kol_full_nm foc_area_id thrc_cd thrc_nm dis_area dis_area_nm expert_score pub_scor rx_scor refrl_scor clincl_rsrchr_scor is_kol
0  101152  7124166.0     Constance Ann Benson           1     VIR     VIR      HIV         HIV        45.17     68.5     0.0       1.69               88.0      Y
1  251489  7822721.0            Mariam S Aziz           1     VIR     VIR      HIV         HIV        44.33     39.5    33.0      34.26               76.0      Y
2  100856  7356682.0     William Rodney Short           1     VIR     VIR      HIV         HIV        49.49     44.0    57.5      50.39               48.0      Y
3  251460  7933108.0             Laura A Guay           1     VIR     VIR      HIV         HIV         34.8     63.0     0.0        0.0               48.0      N
4  100653  7986599.0  Roberto Agustin Andrade           1     VIR     VIR      HIV         HIV        35.07     32.5    42.5       3.21               45.0      N
```

df2.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 501 entries, 0 to 500
Data columns (total 14 columns):
kol_id                501 non-null object
jnj_id                501 non-null object
kol_full_nm           501 non-null object
foc_area_id           501 non-null object
thrc_cd               501 non-null object
thrc_nm               501 non-null object
dis_area              501 non-null object
dis_area_nm           501 non-null object
expert_score          501 non-null object
pub_scor              501 non-null object
rx_scor               501 non-null object
refrl_scor            501 non-null object
clincl_rsrchr_scor    501 non-null object
is_kol                501 non-null object
dtypes: object(14)
```

I am trying to merger these two dataframes but getting empty dataframe. I am running below code:

```
df_3=pd.merge(df2,df1,on=['kol_id', 'jnj_id', 'thrc_nm'],how='inner')
```

In output I am getting:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [kol_id, jnj_id, kol_full_nm, thrc_cd]
Index: []
```

Desirable Output:

```
df_result:

   kol_id   jnj_id    kol_full_nm          thrc_cd  
0  101152   7124166  Constance Ann Benson   VIR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is column `jnj_id` in `df2` is filled by `objects` (`strings`), but there are trailing `0`, so not match. I guess reason is `df1['jnj_id']` was filled by `integers` and `df2['jnj_id']` was filled ny `floats`, co convert to strings cannot help here.

One idea is remove them by [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df2['jnj_id'] = df2['jnj_id'].str.replace('\.0$', '')
```

Or convert both columns to integers or floats:

```
df1['jnj_id'] = df1['jnj_id'].astype(int)
df2['jnj_id'] = df2['jnj_id'].astype(int)
```

---

```
df1['jnj_id'] = df1['jnj_id'].astype(float)
df2['jnj_id'] = df2['jnj_id'].astype(float)
```

Comment: I converted both the dataframes into str but still getting the same error. I used df1 = df1.astype(str)  & df2 = df2.astype(str)

Comment: @shivampatel - Ya, I know. But it seems before `df1['jnj_id']` was integer and `df2['jnj_id']` was floats, so cannot help convert to strigns.

Comment: @shivampatel - In my opinion there is no reason for it, beeter is convert to numeric what should be numeric. Numeric to strings should be converted only if need it - e.g. some codes.